# Rspec not sending out emails with Json post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

My spec:

```
      context 'with valid data' do
        describe 'refers other users' do
          before(:each) do
            post '/shop/referrals', valid_referral_params
            ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
          end

        def valid_referral_params
          { "shop_referral"=>{"sender_email"=>"sender@hotmail.com", "receiver_email_one"=>"myfriend@hotmail.com",
          "receiver_email_two"=>"myfriendd@hotmail.com", "receiver_email_three"=>"myfriendddddd@hotmail.com"}, format: :json }
        end
      end
```

The following test is not passing:

```
  it { expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size).to eq 4 }
```

Pretty much I am sending out 4 emails, currently `expected 4 got 0` and when I remove `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear` I get `expected 4 got 12`

From my model:

```
def send_notifications
  ReferralMailer.referral_sender_email(sender_email).deliver!
  reciever_email_collection.each do |email|
    ReferralMailer.referral_receiver_email(email).deliver!
  end
end
```

And

```
reciever_email_collection = [myfriend1@hotmail.com, myfriend2@hotmail.com, myfriend3@hotmail.com]
```

Also have
`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to reproduce the issue but it looks to me like you're clearing the mail queue after the post request. Have you tried moving the clear before the `post`?